# How to generate a list of a pair of elements in Enlive?

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm new to Enlive. I found that I can iterate with `clone-for`, however, it works for single element. I want to generate a list of a pair of elements like the following:

```
<div>
  <a href="url1">item 1</a><br>
  <a href="url2">item 2</a><br>
  ...
</div>
```

I tried to select `<a>` and use `clone-for`, but end with following result:

```
<div>
  <a href="url1">item 1</a><a href="url2">item 2</a>......<br>
</div>
```

What do I do to repeat `<a>` with `<br>` in each iteration?

Comment: what input do you have?

Comment: @edbond sequence(or vector) of items, like this: `[{:url "url1" :label "item 1"} {:url "url2" :label "item 2"} ... ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [fragments](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/enlive-clj/U-W7wcQR7CI) will work in this case.

Try something along these lines:

```
(html/sniptest "<div><a href=\"url\">Label</a><br/></div>" {[:a] [:br]} 
  (clone-for [{label :label url :url} [{:label "Google" :url "http://www.google.com" }
                                       {:label "Stack Overflow" :url "http://www.stackoverflow.com"}]]
             [:a] (do-> (content label)
                        (set-attr :href url)))))
;; =>
<div>
     <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><br />
     <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a><br />
</div>
```

If you always want the full content of the div to be cloned (not just the fragment `:a -> :br`) then you can use `first-child` and `last-child`. Just change the `{[:a] [:br]}` selector above to `{[:div first-child] [:div last-child]}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that specifying selector like this `{[:a][:br]}` possible. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! These fragment selectors were a new find to me too, so I'm glad you posted the question :).